# T sql query. Identify Start Date / End Date in a date column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need your help.
I use sql server 2012.
This query is for a log application.
I have a table like this:

This is a sample with 2 requestid and here is the result I would like to obtain.

I Have worked on it all week end and still haven't found a solution.
I tried lag and lead function of sql server 2012 but it doesn't work.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#test', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #test;

CREATE TABLE #test
(
    requestid INT,
    eventdate DATETIME,
   eventname VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT #test
(
    requestid,
   eventdate,
    eventname
)
VALUES
(46444, '2016/08/08 10:20:33.000', 'OPENED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 10:33:10.000', 'REVIEWED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 11:09:55.000', 'OPENED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 11:32:41.000', 'REVIEWED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 11:39:01.000', 'CLOSED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 15:00:04.000', 'OPENED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 15:17:40.000', 'REVIEWED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 15:29:36.000', 'OPENED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 15:31:34.000', 'REVIEWED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 15:36:37.000', 'CLOSED'),
(46444, '2016/08/08 17:04:27.000', 'OPENED'),
(46445, '2016/08/10 09:00:00.000', 'OPENED'),
(46445, '2016/08/11 01:33:10.000', 'REVIEWED'),
(46445, '2016/08/12 15:36:37.000', 'CLOSED');

select *
from #test
```

The result

```
requestid   eventdate           eventname    CLOSEDDate      CLOSEDEventname
 46444  2016-08-08 10:33:10.000 REVIEWED    2016-08-08 11:39:01.000 CLOSED
 46444  2016-08-08 15:17:40.000 REVIEWED    2016-08-08 15:36:37.000 CLOSED
 46445  2016-08-11 01:33:10.000 REVIEWED    2016-08-12 15:36:37.000 CLOSED
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the logic for the columns.

Answer (score 1):

I can see what you seem to want.  For each closed date, you want the earliest review date for that close.  You can do this in by just enumerating the closes to assign a group and then aggregating:

```
select requestid,
       min(case when eventname = 'REVIEWED' then eventdate end) as eventdate,
       'REVIEWED' as event,
       max(eventdate) as closedate,
       'CLOSED' as closedeventname
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when eventname = 'CLOSED' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by requestid order by eventdate desc) as grp
      from #test t
     ) t
group by requestid, grp;
Having min(case when eventname = 'REVIEWED' then eventdate end) is not null
```

I'm pretty sure that this produces the output you want.  If you have failed to specify additional rules that you need in the question, I would strongly suggest that you ask *another* question with a better explanation.